# Decrease delay of an agent

Tags: anylogic

In anylogic in Process Modeling Library blocks there is an object called Delay, it has a function **extendDelay**:

> void extendDelay(Agent agent, double dt) - Extends delay for the given
>   agent (if it is possible to pass null as an argument, all delayed
>   agents will be affected).

It does not accept dt with negative number, but I need to decrease the agent delay time, here is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.UnicastService:
Parameter dt has invalid value: -0.9652996653680965
```

My question is: how can I **decrease a delay time or set a new delay time** for an Agent and is it possible to do so without exiting Delay object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways, depends on what really happens in the model.

One option: Replace the Delay object with a Wait object. This has a method to `myWait.free(agent)`which you can use to free any specific agent at any point you like, i.e. whenever you model determines "now is the time".

No need to reduce/amend delay durations.

Another way might be to switch your Delay mode from the default "specified time" to "Until stopDelay() is called", at the top of the Delay object properties. Now all agents wait until you call them out directly. Again, might be more elegant than to reduce wait times.

cheers

Comment: delay object suits well for my problem: I have 1 source and 1 delay object, the delay time equals N*du/C, where C is a constant(f.e. 5 bits/sec.) and N is number of devices being served and du is a constant(f.e. 20 bits). What I need is to recalculate the remaining service(delay) time each time new agent arives on the delay object or leaves it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ben that you should use a wait block... it sounds more natural to me... But if you insist to use a delay no matter what, then this is what you can do:

1. Create a variable in your agent called totalReduction of type double initial value 0
2. Create an event called reduceDelay in your agent triggered by timeout and mode user control... in the action of the delay you will have `main.delay.stopDelay(this);`
3. now... every time you want to reduce the delay time you can use the following code, assuming that "a" is the agent you want to reduce the delay

   `double remainingDelay=delay.getRemainingTime(a)`;
   `double delayReduction=4`;//or whatever time you want to reduce
   `a.totalReduction+=delayReduction`;
   `double newRemainingDelay=remainingDelay-a.totalReduction`;
   `if(newRemainingDelay<=0)`{
       `delay.stopDelay(a)`;
   }
   else{
          `a.reduceDelay.restart(newRemainingDelay)`;
   }